# Cannot add AWS Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags

I've got some AWS S3 resources to which I'd like to add tags.  I'm trying to add a tag with a key of `SensitiveResource`.  The resources already have some existing System tags -- `aws:cloudformation:logical-id` and a few others.  When I try to add the new tag, I get the following error message:
`us-west-1:TagService:addResourceTags com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Your TagKey cannot be prefixed with aws:`

The AWS documentation states that you cannot use `aws:` as a prefix for a tag key, which is fine, and that makes sense.  But I'm not trying to do that in this case: the `aws:` prefixed tags are already existing and my new tag does not have this as a prefix.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or can I just no longer add any tags to a resource once it has been created by CloudFormation and has the `aws:` system tags associated?

Comment: What method are you trying to add the tag with (e.g. AWS CLI, one of the SDKs, etc.) Can you provide the command or code you are executing in an attempt to add the tag?  To answer your last question, you are able to manually add additional tags to resources created by CloudFormation after the fact.

Comment: I'm using the AWS Console to try to add the additional tags.  ResourceGroups->TagEditor.  Select a set of resources and type in the new tag in the TagKey column.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'am having the same issue.

Comment: According to AWS Support, it is a bug on their end.  I don't think I found a resolution as it just wasn't that important.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have also run into a bug w/ S3; namly the inability to use `_` in bucket names. Filed a ticket with them, waiting to hear back.